# Remote Desktop via c# acceder con credenciales y ejecutar comando

Tags: c#, rdp

buen dia.

quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme con algo, realmente estoy muy perdido, tratare de explicarlo de la mejor manera que pueda.

Tengo 3 servidores

2.61  <- servicio API que obtiene un token y un documento

```
a) ingreso a un navegador web con una url
b) ingreso credenciales especiales de este servicio 
c) obtengo el token y el documento (es un json y un csv)
```

2.14  <- servicio WSDL que procesa el token y el documento

```
a) ingreso credenciales de este servicio (distintas a 2.61)
b) subo con un control web en una url el token y el documento
c) obtengo una serie de documentos para descargar en una interfaz web
```

2.10  <- servicio de carga de varios segundos documento expedido por 2.14

```
a) ingreso los documentos de la interfaz web de 2.61  
b) espero un    proceso por lotes y luego la interfaz me indica si estan bien 
c) de estar bien los documentos sin problema de estar erroneos tengo que  formular un correo con los errores a una direccion designada
```

mi intencion es construir un programa que ingrese desde otra pc hacia estos tres servidores y quiero hacerlo en c# quizas en asp.net pero no se si es posible siquiera, los servicios son consumidos y no son de mi propiedad tampoco tengo acceso a los fuentes.

cada uno de esos los obtengo ingresando una url en un navegador, asi que mi problema principal es abrir una venta? (no se si es ventana en un asp.net) para ingresar credenciales de windows y con ellas ir abriendo y ejecutando los navegadores en cada maquina virtual.

¿ Es posible manipular una ventana despues de conectar una sesion de c#? revisaba que es posible interactuar con aplicaciones de windows usando la API de Automation descrita aqui:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal

ya he realizado esto pero en aplicaciones de desktop y son cosas sencillas de input data para formularios en aplicaciones de legado, especificamente usando un framework que abstrae esto lo usan en UI testing.

¿Es posible interactuar con esa API desde una sesion de remote desktop? es decir establezco la conexion y con esa conexion identifico las aplicaciones ejecutadas en la maquina virtual, identifico los controles y los manipulo.

gracias por leerme cualquier orientacion es bienvenida.

Comment: No termino de entender el problema concreto. Obviamente no es asp, porque esto no es una web que se comunica a otra web, y menos que menos desde la web. Si haces un programa de escritorio, cual seria el problema? tu pregunta esta muy basada en opiniones.

Comment: Tampoco entiendo que tiene que er rdp aca.. si vos no queres conectarte via rdp, solo queres acceder a una api y etc?

Comment: perdon, las acciones las hago yo, desde mi maquina no puedo consumir los servicios que estan en cada maquina virtual.   por eso tengo que entrar escribir mis credenciales y hacerlo, lo que intento es hacer un programar que al brindarle mis credenciales ingrese a la maquina virtual y haga ciertas operaciones y principalmente saber si siquiera es posible